# exception exit: eaccess on windows 10

Tags: tcp, erlang, windows-10

I have an erlang TCP server that works without a problem on everything but windows.
There it reports the error in the title of this question. I tries to disable the firewall in windows. Still I get the same error. What could the issue be?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

eacces is a posix message, it means that the code attempts to access to a file or a directory without the necessary rights. In the error message, you should have the line of code responsible for this error, and the call stack.

Comment: I get not further info than ***exception exit: eaccess

Comment: You are right, usually, when an exception is generated you can get more information using `catch expression`, but you need to modify the code and have an idea where the problem could occur. A first step could be to check the right access of your files and directories, and the owner of the erlang program.

Comment: And I tought that was a unix/linux prerogative to have access right issue. I will check. Thanks